# Website (with many Canvas-HTML5-Images) crashes on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

I use [**ChartNew.js**](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js) (a further development by François "FVANCOP", who spiced up the original [Chart.js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js)) to draw charts via html5-Canvas. This looks really good and is interactive, too. I love it.

The problem: I have for reasons around 40 canvas-objects on one internetsite. Via desktop-Browser everything is smooth and cool, but on mobile browsers the site crashes after - let me think - three images. I tested it on Tablets and Smartphones with the most popular mobile browsers. Nothing is immune.

**I won't switch the system, basically and theoretically it's fine. I tested it with two charts - and it looks really good, even on a smartphone! I'd like to know, why is this happening? Canvas is a html5-object and I thought it's proper - more than ever on mobile devices.**

It could be a performance issue, for sure. Therefore I deactivate for mobile browsers the built-in animation AND jquery.appear (the canvas gettingload, if they are on the screen, not before)... but I couldn't achieve any improvement.

Maybe YOU have a hint for me or you already know a solution? That would be awesome! :-)

Comment: hint 1: memory issue. hint 2: re-use the elements (max number of elements should be what fits on the display).

Comment: *which* mobile browser are you talking about?

Comment: @Philipp I've tried the site with firefox, 'internet' (android) and google chrome.

Comment: @Epistemex But the site already crashes when 3 charts (which are visible on one screen) are placed.

Comment: @Sebastian if all browsers are on the same phone/OS it could be a low-level issue with the sub-system for graphics. Canvas should never crash the browser.

Comment: @Epistemex Thank you for your reply. I've tested the script on a tablet (a 2 years old one) and on my smartphone - the HTC One, which (I guess) is no low-level device ;-) But if you say so, I should search somewhere else then only on the canvas. Really odd and strange problem.